# My site's content on the side is going under the footer

Tags: html, css

I made some content on the side which is supposed to be overlapping but not going over the footer, like the page should be longer so to say which it's not. I don't really know how to word it but I want the side panel/the recent news to be dragged down and then the footer is at the bottom right when the `recent-news` ends.

My HTML code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>EcoNews</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="assets/img/icon.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><h1>EcoNews</h1></a>
      
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Account</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#login">Login</a>
              <a href="#signup">Signup</a>
          </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>
    
   <aside>
    <div class="container recent-news">
        <ul>
          <li class="article">
            <h1>Title of news page</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetodit</p>
            <img src="assets/img/icon.png">
          </li>
          <li class="article">
            <h1>Title of news page</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetodit</p>
            <img src="assets/img/icon.png">
          </li>
          <li class="article">
            <h1>Title of news page</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetodit</p>
            <img src="assets/img/icon.png">
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <footer>
    <h2>EcoNews</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Recent News</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

My CSS code

```
body {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

/* Global tags */
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* Header */
header {
    background-color: #449342;
}

.logo {
    width: 10%;
}

/* selects all a tag in the header instead change it to class specific for the top */

header a:hover {
    font-size: 20px;
}

header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Navigation */
nav {
    background-color: #2EAF7D;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    margin-bottom: 0%;
}

nav ul li {
    margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
    display: inline;

}

nav ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

/* Nav dropdown */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Recent articles */
.recent-articles {
    background-color: chartreuse;
    width: 50%;
}

.recent-articles ul {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

/* News content */
.recent-news {
    background-color: #449342;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}

.recent-news ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0%;
}

.article {
    border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}

/* Article Title */
.article h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

/* Article body paragraph */
.article p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Article Image */
.article img {
    width: 10%;
}

/* Footer */
footer {
    background-color: #2EAF7D;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

footer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0%;
}

footer li {
    display: inline;
}

footer ul li a {
    margin: 0% 3%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

footer ul li a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
footer{ clear: both; }
```

If you could post the whole html markup, it would be nice. I would recommend you using flexbox for site layout

Comment: How could I use flexbox for my site, is there any docs or an example you could give?
And will edit my post now with the whole HTML markup and css code

Comment: Try the code I gave you let's know if it worked for you.

Comment: Your code didn't do anything sir, any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I've been offline for a while now. Are you still facing issues with this?